# purity of soul according to gita

Tags: shiva, gita

I have gone through some translation of the following verses of the shiva gita:

> तस्यैवांशो जीवलोके हृदये प्राणिनां स्थितः ।
> विस्फुलिङ्गा यथा वह्नेर्जायन्ते काष्ठयोगतः ॥ २८॥
>
> अनादिकर्मसंबद्धास्तद्वदंशा महेशितुः ।
> अनादिवासनायुक्ताः क्षेत्रज्ञा इति ते स्मृताः ॥ २९॥

According to one translation by [P.K Sundaram](https://archive.org/details/SivaGita/page/n45/mode/2up), the translation for above reads:

[image]

and another translation(in hindi) says:

[image]

The second line in the second translation is pointing toward the confusion. The atma(supreme self) is supposed to the the kshetragya, but the atma is pure, then why does it say that the kshetragya is said to be filled with mortal desires?

Comment: Basically,Kshetragya is the knower/seer of Kshetra/seen.A bound jivatma because of avidya/ignorance sees Prakriti and its variations i.e. ego, body, world, mind etc., and identify itself with it which leads to endless desires even at the deathbed and hence leads to reincarnation.This is also explained in Geeta chapter 13 & 8, '13.22
When the puruṣh (individual soul) seated in prakṛiti (the material energy) desires to enjoy the three guṇas, attachment to them becomes the cause of its birth in superior and inferior wombs.Within the body also resides the Supreme Lord.He is said to be the Witness

Comment: If you considered 2 souls one is jivattma and other is paramatthma residing in the hearts being where one is witness other us enjoyer of the materialistic karma this is know as kshetrayagna as stated in vedas simple interpretation  is complicated in case if advaita you have  keshtrayagna is the enjoyer oc fruits of action

Comment: @PrasannaR , although it's not pointed out exactly as if there are two or one soul somewhere we get hints that there are and somewhere we get that the god resides as soul. And that soul with the tainted antakaran is jiva. In both the cases, it's hard to interpret the lines above

Answer (score 2):

The soul is very pure according to [this](https://detechter.com/7-things-the-bhagavad-gita-says-about-the-soul/). One reason is that the soul has no birth or death. It also has no past, present, and future. Even when you die, the soul doesn't go away.

Comment: please interpret it according to the slokas above

Comment: @juztcode  i will interpret it with some slokas

Comment: @juztcode     i will do it

Comment: Never mind I just got the bounty